# extract digit from string using replace or extract method in Java

Tags: java

Example:
I/p : "its 2 3 4  5 n and ita 3 5"
O/p : 2345
So it should remove all white spaces from the digit

i tried couple of regex expression inside string.replace() but none of them worked .please help me

Comment: @Jens if you want to replace with regex use `replaceAll()`, and also `\s` matches only the white spaces, you should use `\D` for none digits.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help

```
String numbers = str.replaceAll("\\D","");
```

Comment: @kuhelimalakar your input and output are not clear, provide a better sample so we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this.

```
String yourValue = "its 2 3 4 5 n and ita 3 5";
yourValue  = yourValue .replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
System.out.println(a);
```

Edit: I just realized, that your questeion is a bit confusing also. In my example the output would be "234535", which is different from what you wrote in your question. But I think there is no generalizable solution for this, that you want to cut off everything starting from the n if you really do want this.

Comment: Yes, there might not be any generalized solution but i want output should be 2345 only. Your  solution also helpful for me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull all numerical values from a String then you can do something like this:

```
String string = "its 2 3 4 5 n and 32.45 it's a 3 5".replace(" ","");
       
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d{1,3}(,?\\d{2,3})*?\\.?\\d+|-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group());
}

// Display the list contents.
System.out.println(list);
```

As you can see, this code can capture signed or unsigned Integer or floating point values from a string.

For the Regular Expression explaination, see the **Tools** section within [this link](https://regexr.com/60j1r).

Comment: Thank you i will try it now